# пропущен абзац кода в книге Паласиоса - Программирование искусственного интеллекта в играх

Tags: разработка-игр

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пункт 22? ни у кого нет абзаца с кодом, может пригодиться... в англ версиях epub и pdf качал - тоже самое только "C" и всё.

Comment: Демо- версия :)

Comment: попробуйте исходники вот тут скачать https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/support/24429

Comment: хорошо бы! но что-то оттуда никак. ввожу ввожу оно только страницу обновляет

Comment: Видимо не выполнено условие `If you have purchased a Packt book` Ну или подождите: `We will e-mail you with a direct link to the code download`

Comment: Нужно читать бумажные версии)) А если и там косяк - надо сообщить автору как минимум...хотя и сейчас надо бы издателей уведомить

Comment: да, видимо не выполнено условие :)

Answer (score 1):

там нет другого кода никакого, в смысле - указан полный. если есть желание посмотреть скачайте файл(не вижу возможности присоединить здесь) с указанного выше в ответе сайта под названием TFRival.cs чтобы скачать - покупать книгу необязательно. в pdf-версии просто опускаем неуказаный код из п.22